# how to generate certificates for new peers in Organization in Hyperledger Fabric 1.0

Tags: ibm-cloud, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I am using Hyperledger Fabric 1.0 fabric-node-sdk  tutorial (https ://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-node/test ).
    And I have setup the two organization each 1 with peer(peer0 in org1 and peer2 in org2).
    My requirement is to add one more peer in each organization(peer1 in Org1 and peer3 in Org2).
    I believe need to create peer1 and peer3 folder inside \tls folder and place some ".pem" files
    example:
    "src\github.com\hyperledger\fabric-sdk-node\test\fixtures\tls\peers\peer1"
    "src\github.com\hyperledger\fabric-sdk-node\test\fixtures\tls\peers\peer3"
    "ca-cert.pem"
    "cert.pem"
    "key.pem"

And also need to create admincerts ,cacerts,keystore,signcerts folders and respective ".pem" with respect to corresponding peers in below folders

"fabric-sdk-node\test\fixtures\channel\crypto-config\peerOrganizations\org1.example.com\peers\peer1.org1.example.com"
"fabric-sdk-node/test/fixtures/channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer3.org2.example.com"

Could you please help me to know the steps to generate these certificate files and register these new peers to network.

I have tried to CA client to register and enroll peer to peerOrg1

```
fabric-ca-client register --id.name peer3 --id.type peer --id.affiliation org1.department1 --id.secret peer3pw  
fabric-ca-client enroll -u http://peer3:peer3pw@localhost:7054 -M $FABRIC_CA_HOME/msp
```

But getting the error :

```
2017/05/03 09:18:30 http: TLS handshake error from [::1]:55890: tls: oversized record received with length 21536   
2017/05/03 09:19:04 http: TLS handshake error from 192.168.132.17:53220: tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake
2017/05/03 09:19:04 http: TLS handshake error from 192.168.132.17:53221: tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake
2017/05/03 09:20:25 http: TLS handshake error from [::1]:55891: tls: oversized record received with length 21536
```

I followed below steps to add new peer in org1

1) In CA container (ca_peerOrg1)

```
export FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME=$HOME/fabric-ca/clients/admin
fabric-ca-client enroll -u http://admin:adminpw@localhost:7054
fabric-ca-client register --id.name peer1 --id.type peer --id.affiliation org1.department1 --id.secret peer1pw
export FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME=$HOME/fabric-ca/clients/peer1
fabric-ca-client enroll -u http://peer1:peer1pw@localhost:7054 -M $FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME/msp
```

And I am gtting the error:

```
Post failure [Post http://localhost:7054/enroll : malformed HTTP response "\x15\x03\x01\x00\x02\x02\x16"] ; not sending
```

2) I have replace hostname to container id (e2598895c822) while executing the command , Still getting the same error

3) error in ca_peerOrg1 container log:

```
error : ca_peerOrg1 | 2017/05/03 11:43:02 http: TLS handshake error from [::1]:55913: tls: oversized record received with length 21536
```

4) I observed docker composed yaml file is staring the ca_peerOrg1 container with command tag (sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start --ca.certfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/org2.example.com-cert.pem --ca.keyfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/464d550fe9bf9e7d8976cdf59d1a5d472598f54c058c3546317c5c5fb0ddfd6e_sk -b admin:adminpw' -d)

I added one more CA server details in docker compose file with command tag (sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw) as:

fabric-ca-server:
   image: hyperledger/fabric-ca
   container_name: fabric-ca-server
   ports:
     - "9054:7054"
   environment:
     - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
   volumes:
     - "./fabric-ca-server:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server"
   command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw'

5) Then I have login to the fabric-ca-server container and excuted below commands

```
fabric-ca-client enroll -u http://admin:adminpw@localhost:7054
    fabric-ca-client register --id.name peer1 --id.type peer --id.affiliation org1.department1 --id.secret peer1pw
    export FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME=$HOME/fabric-ca/clients/peer1
    fabric-ca-client enroll -u http://peer1:peer1pw@localhost:7054 -M $FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME/msp

And this time it was successful. And MSP folder got created (with cacert,keystore,signcerts) in container.
```

6) Since I was trying add Peer in org1 , so I login to again container ca_peerOrg1
    and got the cerificate from fabric-ca-server  using below commands

```
export FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME=$HOME/fabric-ca/clients/peer1
    fabric-ca-client getcacert -u http://2f67d7031c3f:7054 -M $FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME/msp

And observed that msp folder got imported to ca_peerOrg1.
```

7) created one folder peer1 in hyperledger\fabric-sdk-node\test\fixtures\tls\peers\ 
    and copied the newly created cacert,keystore,signcerts folders with certificates. And renamed /cacert/3002372bba75.pem to  /cacert/ca-cert.pem
    admincerts folder i have copied from peer0 folder
8)Also 5)   created one folder "peer1.org1.example.com"  in “\hyperledger\fabric-sdk-node\test\fixtures\channel\crypto-config\peerOrganizations\org1.example.com\peers\” and copied cacert,keystore,signcerts,admincerts folder.

9) updated the   /hyperledger/fabric-sdk-node/test/integration/e2e/config.json with peer2 entry in org1

```
{
        "test-network": {
                "orderer": {
                        "url": "grpcs://localhost:7050",
                        "server-hostname": "orderer0",
                        "tls_cacerts": "../../fixtures/tls/orderer/ca-cert.pem"
                },
                "org1": {
                        "name": "peerOrg1",
                        "mspid": "Org1MSP",
                        "ca": "https://localhost:7054",
                        "peer1": {
                                "requests": "grpcs://localhost:7051",
                                "events": "grpcs://localhost:7053",
                                "server-hostname": "peer0",
                                "tls_cacerts": "../../fixtures/tls/peers/peer0/ca-cert.pem"
                        },
                        "peer2": {
                                "requests": "grpcs://localhost:9051",
                                "events": "grpcs://localhost:9053",
                                "server-hostname": "peer1",
                                "tls_cacerts": "../../fixtures/tls/peers/peer1/ca-cert.pem"
                        }

                },
                "org2": {
                        "name": "peerOrg2",
                        "mspid": "Org2MSP",
                        "ca": "https://localhost:8054",
                        "peer1": {
                                "requests": "grpcs://localhost:8051",
                                "events": "grpcs://localhost:8053",
                                "server-hostname": "peer2",
                                "tls_cacerts": "../../fixtures/tls/peers/peer2/ca-cert.pem"
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

10)Created one more docker file “docker-compose_peer1.yaml” , which contains only details of peer1
and started docker compose and now  these containers are up (ca_peerOrg2,ca_peerOrg1,orderer0,couchdb,peer2,peer0,peer1,fabric-ca-server)

11) executing below comaands and its failing
Cd /hyperledger1.0.0/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-node/test/integration/e2e
node create-channel.js 
node join-channel.js

```
routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed.
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: Connect Failed
    at ClientDuplexStream._emitStatusIfDone (/root/hyperledger1.0.0/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-node/node_modules/grpc/src/node/src/client.js:201:19)
    at ClientDuplexStream._readsDone (/root/hyperledger1.0.0/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-node/node_modules/grpc/src/node/src/client.js:
```

could you plese help me to to know the steps i am following is correct. Please help me to add new peer.

Comment: Did you manage to solve it? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error "tls: oversized record received with length 21536" occurs when you specify "http" in the URL for the fabric-ca-client, but the fabric-ca-server was started with TLS enabled and therefore is listening on "https".
But since it worked using http on the fabric-ca-client when logging into the container but does not work from your host, my guess is that there is another instance of fabric-ca-server running on your host and has TLS enabled.

Answer (score 0):

To generate the crypto material (using [cryptogen extends](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/commands/cryptogen-commands.html#the-cryptogen-extend-command)) for the new peer, you need to edit the crypto-config.yaml file and then execute:

```
cryptogen extend --config=./crypto-config.yaml
```

You can find the complete guide at

[Extending Hyperledger Fabric Network: Adding a new peer](https://medium.com/@wahabjawed/extending-hyperledger-fabric-network-adding-a-new-peer-4f52f70a7217)